# Почему не срабатывает flex-grow

Tags: css

```css
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
}
img{
  display: block;
}

figure{
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

p{
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <figure><img src="https://c.wallhere.com/photos/e5/b1/new_city_travel_newzealand_sky_cloud_lake_storm-1045201.jpg!s" alt=""></figure>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, amet atque consequuntur cum est eum harum hic magnam maxime minus molestiae nesciunt nostrum numquam obcaecati officiis possimus recusandae reiciendis sapiente velit. Autem beatae delectus doloremque et explicabo molestiae non quia temporibus voluptates! Ab ad dolore eveniet, itaque nulla quibusdam. Ad adipisci amet, assumenda consequatur dolore doloribus facere illum ipsa laudantium magnam maiores minima nihil odit omnis porro praesentium, quas quia quidem ratione repellat repudiandae, sapiente sequi sunt tenetur totam voluptas voluptate</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете работу свойства `flex-grow`. В вашем случае оно работает, только результат не соответствует вашим ожиданиям.

Answer (score -1):

Потому что у вас у `img` и `figure` стоит `display: block;`, замените на `display: flex;`

Comment: поменял - вообще фигня какая-то: картинка стала флексом и заполнила все доступное по высоте, место

Comment: Так а в ынапишите, что именно вы хотите получить. Вы спросили что сделать чтобы `flex-grow` срабатывал - я ответил.

Comment: так я и написал - почему не срабатывает свойство flex-grow? В данном коде установлено значение у элемента figure - 1, то есть ему отдается 1/3 доступного места, а элементу `p` - 2/3 оставшегося места

Comment: А вы мне предлагаете установить этим элементам flex и они естественно заполнят все свободное место. А flex-grow дает возможность поделить ширину flex-блока. Вот здесь все понятно и доступно описано: https://webref.ru/css/flex-grow